# When are S and T uncorrelated based on the marginal distributions of X and Y? With S = X - Y and T = X + Y

Tags: probability, covariance, correlation, marginal-distribution

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$, with $S = X - Y$ and $T = X + Y$.
Under what constraint on the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are $S$ and $T$ uncorrelated.

I know that $S$ and $T$ are uncorrelated if the $Cov(S, T) = 0$.

If two variables $S$ and $T$ are independent their covariance has to be 0.
So now I want to know in what cases $S$ and $T$ are independent based on the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do **not** need to know whether $S$ and $T$ are independent.  Just concentrate on the covariance.  Expand out $\text{Cov}(X-Y, X+Y)$ using the properties of covariance and you'll see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the properties of the covariance, one gets the desired relation between $X$ and $Y$:

\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}(S,T) & = \text{Cov}(X - Y,X + Y)\\\\
& = \text{Cov}(X,X) + \text{Cov}(X,Y) - \text{Cov}(Y,X) - \text{Cov}(Y,Y)\\\\
& = \mathbb{V}(X) - \mathbb{V}(Y) = 0
\end{align*}

Comment: How do we know that the Var(X) - Var(Y) = 0?

Comment: @BartelJaap That is because $\text{Cov}(X,Y) = \text{Cov}(Y,X)$, $\text{Cov}(X,X) = \mathbb{V}(X)$ and $\text{Cov}(Y,Y) = \mathbb{V}(Y)$.

Comment: Still don't understand why that would be a reason for $Var(X)$ to be equal to the $Var(Y)$